# normal popup window on click - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, popup

I have a form with name and id `testform` containing an `<input type="text" name="name" id="name">` and a button next to it `<input type="button" name="check" id="check">`. I want to open a new window (if possible with parameters such as height, width, toolbar etc) on click of button with a specific url `www.example.com/test.php?`.

I am looking for something like

```
 $('#check').live('click', function() {
                window.location = "url";
                return false;
        });
```

How can I make this possible??

Thanks in advance... `:)`

blasteralfred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.open(url, "name", "height=512, width=512");
```

You can also give it focus like this:

```
popup = window.open(url, "name", "height=512, width=512");
popup.focus()
```

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Comment: hi @shadyabhi, i want another window

Comment: @shadyabhi, see Shyju's answer for that. As far as I can see, the asker wanted a browser popup, i.e. a new browser window.

Comment: @blasteralfred, you are not even using my code. Why are you assigning to `window.open`?

Comment: hi @ Harpyon, where should i put ur code?? or can u modify the code for me?? :)

Comment: @blasteralfred, you didn't write the code yourself, did you? Anyway, here... http://paste.pocoo.org/show/363948/

Comment: no, my developer did.. 'm trying to debug.. any way.. thank you so much for your help `:)`  ...  it works....

Answer (score 1):

Opening another browser

http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm

If you want to open some modal popup ,consider jQuery UI modal dialog or thickbox /fancybox

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/